# BigQuery "Query History" became corrupted

Tags: google-bigquery

After trying to drop table from BigQuery using "DROP TABLE '[Table Name]'" query from the web UI (query failed), the "Query History" page of the project became corrupted.

The list of query bullets still exists, but there's no data - it's empty (this is the actual screenshot, the image was not edited):
[image]

The queries are still accessible using the CLI:

- Listing all query jobs: `bq ls -j -q`
- Getting the data for specific job: `bq show --format=prettyjson -j <Job ID>`

New queries are listed OK (in another project with the same issue), but all the old ones are missing from the web UI.

Comment: Please [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) with whatever other information you can provide, such as the ID of the job that issued the `DROP TABLE` statement. You've tried refreshing the UI, I assume, right?

Comment: Refresh. Close tab & open a new tab. Nothing helps.